# What is the relationship between sockets and ports?

Tags: networking, sockets

I am trying to understand the relationship between sockets and ports. I found that a socket is part of a port and it handles communication for that port. However, on another blog I read

> Os does not have to support sockets to support TCP or UDP !

So, if the OS on the server does not support sockets, then how will the communication happen on a specific port?

Can someone guide me and provide a simple explanation of the relationship between ports and sockets and what exactly the role of each in communication is?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/152457/3789550

Answer (score 0):

Socket is practical address on application layer for communication.
Format of socket address is `ip_address:protocol:port`. More about socket address you can find [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.progcomc/ch9_sockets.htm).

Example:

```
192.168.1.1:tcp:80
```

this represent socket address of pc with ip address `192.168.1.1` witch "expect" connection on `port 80` if you use `tcp` protocol.

Example from my pc

```
xxx@xxx ~ $ netstat -tp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name     
tcp        0      0 xxx.local:54595     104.16.17.44:http       ESTABLISHED 32294/chrome
```

explantion of this session

- my pc communicate with `104.16.17.44`
- connection is established
- we use `tcp` protocol
- my pc hit remote port 80 aka http port

Overview

this represent communication of

my pc with socket address `xxx.local:54595:tcp` and remote pc with socket `104.16.17.44:http:tcp`

Port is practically "hole" for connection.
But on "hole" named `port 80` you can use any service.
On `port 80` you can serve any service on server. like ftp, ssh, pop3 or any other.

Well known "hole" aka well known ports, more about port you have [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

Port is part of socket address.

Ports and sockets ar part of `tcp stack`. Nice explination heve [here](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-tcp-ip-network-stack/).

`Tcp stack` is only one modul of OS.